# how can I use function SUM() inside of SUM function in Presto SQL?

Tags: presto

I m trying to get SUM of two numbers by following following logic:
x = y + j 
based on this logic I wrote presto query using SUM() function in order to get SUM of x and y but I got Presto syntax error

```
SELECT
 SUM(sum(CASE
        WHEN source = 'x' THEN num_tasks
        ELSE 0 
    END) + sum(CASE WHEN source = 'y' THEN num_tasks ELSE 0  END)) as total
```

Error notice
Presto query failed. Error: SYNTAX_ERROR: Cannot nest aggregations inside aggregation 'sum': ["sum"((CASE WHEN (source = 'y') THEN count ELSE 0 END)), "sum"((CASE WHEN (source = 'x') THEN num_tasks ELSE 0 END))]

Comment: It looks like you can't use `Sum` within `Sum` the way you want according to the SQL documentation.  Instead, try something like `SUM(SELECT FIELD_1, FIELD_2 from TABLE_1, TABLE_2)`.  Then you can pull back the columns you want to sum up all at once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do, but I think the following changes may help:

- Use an `IN` statement in [`CASE WHEN`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#case):  `source in ('x', 'y')`
- Use [`IF`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#if) instead of `CASE`: `if(source in ('x', 'y'), num_tasks, 0)`
- I believe you only need one `SUM` call.

Putting this all together:

```
SELECT SUM(if(source in ('x', 'y'), num_tasks, 0))
```

Alternatively, you can use the `SUM` with `FILTER` syntax:

```
SELECT SUM(num_tasks) filter (where source in ('x', 'y'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as an addition to @Dain Sundstrom's answer: Using conditional summing

```
SELECT SUM(if(source in ('x', 'y'), num_tasks, 0))
```

and filtering like

```
SELECT SUM(num_tasks) filter (where source in ('x', 'y'))
```

can even be combined. Why should I use this? Just imagine you had an issue in prod and one machine did write data with wrong factor (e.g. 1000x). Any price greater than 1000, but just for source 'x' or 'y'.

This could be fixed by

```
SELECT sum(if(price >= 1000000, price/1000, price)),0) 
filter (where source in ('x', 'y')) as revenue
```

So I'd use a conditional IF statement if it's about manipulating the metric itself and filtering if it's about the input records to be processed. This way you stay open to add the other processing on top with minimal changes later on.